# can't play sounds with different frequency in the same scenario

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

In the same game scenario i tried to play several sounds:one music file sound and some sound effects(like lasers hitting a ship or launching a torpedo).These work well with the classic setting values of pygame.mixer.So i typed :

```
pygame.mixer.init(22050, -16, 2, 4096)
```

However i want to play a sound file when this scenario starts(a voice) and after many tries it seems this sound should be played at a frequency of 30000 to be just right.So i want to play all the sounds in the scenario at the 22050 frequency,except this one, which i want to play at the right 30000 frequency and i can't do that in the same time.Here's what i tried:

```
pygame.mixer.init(30000, -16, 2, 4096)
die = pygame.mixer.Sound('die.ogg')
die.set_volume(0.40)
die.play(0)
pygame.mixer.quit()
pygame.mixer.init(22050, -16, 2, 4096)
pygame.mixer.music.load('Sounds/through space.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

This doesn't play the 'die.ogg' sound file.Or,if i delete the lines:

```
pygame.mixer.quit()
pygame.mixer.init(22050,-16, 2, 4096)
```

the other sounds dont play well.Should i remove the 'die' sound object and his frequency or is there another way to keep playing all the sounds well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open your sounds in audio editing software. (Audacity is free).  Most of the time you could drag-and-drop but there is usually a file>import option.

Import a single file.  File>Bounce or File>Export the same file and carefully look at the options. You should be able to choose file format, sample rate, and bit depth.  After you have these set the way you want, finish your bounce.

Repeat this process for each individual sound file, using the same bounce settings each time.

This is the cleanest solution.  You will know your sample rates.  If your program is expecting 44,100Hz (44.1k) sample rate and only gets a 30k recording, it will be played back too fast.